# No such file or directory, Unable to find Python.exe in docker container when running console app in .net core

Tags: c#, python, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .net Core (version 2.2) console app that executes a python script via the command line. However, when i dockerize the project I get a file not found exception. From the error, the dockerized app is unable to locate python.exe and execute the python script.

I have installed python from the dockerfile as shown.
Plus I have attempted to use command " docker exec -it  /bin/bash " to find the python.exe and change the path given in the .Net Core program.

.Net-Core code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "python.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "myScript.py";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

python code:

```py
print("Hello c#")
```

dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443


FROM python:3.7
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
ENV http_proxy=http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX
ENV https_proxy=http://XXX.XXX.XX.XX:XXXX
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myCode/MyProject.csproj"]
RUN dotnet restore "myCode/MyProject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myCode"
RUN dotnet build "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app
ENV http_proxy=
ENV https_proxy=


FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll", "python"]
```

Expected Output:
" Hello C# " 
from in console.

Comment: There are no *.exe files on Linux

Comment: what would you suggest I should swap the python.exe with?

Comment: With the linux version if it of course. But you probably first have install it when the container image is built. Always make sure to test your application in same environment as in production. When you publish it to linux container, test on a linux container (i.e. docker for windows mit linux support not the windows container image, you can only run one at the same time on the dev machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and was getting the same error as you. I just changed the file name like `StartInfo.FileName = "python3"` and then it started working.